# Firewall / router appliance changed LAN IP

Tags: router

I had a strange occurrence with my RVS4000 firewall/router this week. This router has been installed and working without problem for many years now.

However, this week I had a DHCP machine act 'funny' on reboot - it didn't properly catch all the DHCP settings from the server (which is the RVS4000).

What I discovered is the RVS4000 changed it's LAN IP from 10.1.1.1 to a totally different IP 192.xxx.1.1. That took the gateway with it and messed up the DHCP tables.

This box has WAN admin turned off, and I checked for known problems / vulnerabilities, but none seemed to be appropriate. Most require inside (LAN) access and I'm the only one here.

Also weird is that during this incident the router still responded to 10.1.1.1 (and to the other lan address as well).

I reset the LAN IP to 10.1.1.1 and the DHCP settings all came back after reboot, and all is fine again.

BUT - has anyone heard anything about this router spontaneously resetting it's LAN IP before?

Comment: This thing has had several severe exploitable security holes over its lifetime, is EOL and no longer supported. Probably the best fix is a large hammer. It's been awarded a perfect 10 on the CVE scale, who knows what other code insecurities lurk in a consistent 9+ CVE performer.

Comment: Yea, no kidding. This thing's been on autopilot for so long without a problem. I just found out today the thing had been set with the telnet port enabled, and that the port faces both LAN and WAN. What a horrible design. Anyway, turned off the telnet port today and will see...

Comment: Yeah, Cisco has been running on autopilot as well in the security and code QA environment, a series of enterprise grade equipment had to be emergency patched last week because they'd been running with a locked in admin account with locked in password. Don't trust Cisco if it's not being given currently supported firmware upgrades and the latest ones coming out are "PATCH IMMEDIATELY".

Comment: I guess it's time to add some NICs to my OpenBSD firewall that serves another network and toss this thing away.